# How to write a trigger with two addError conditions at different places on the same record?

Tags: apex, trigger

**Sample Trigger**:

```
trigger AccTrigger2 on Account (before insert) {

    //Condition I am adding and this should run before the other condition.
    for(Account accObj: Trigger.new){
        if(accObj.Name.equalsIgnoreCase('Test')){
            accObj.addError('Name cannot be test');
            return;
        }
    }

    //Condition already present in the system
    for(Account accObj: Trigger.new){
        if(accObj.BillingState.equalsIgnoreCase('MA')){
            accObj.addError('Please select different state');
        }       
    }

}
```

**Below records are coming into the trigger**:

1. Name = 'Test', BillingState = 'CA'
2. Name = 'Test', BillingState = 'MA'
3. Name = 'Acme', BillingState = 'MA'
4. Name = 'Acme', BillingState = 'CA'

**Output I am trying achieve:**

[image]

**Output 1**(with return statement in the trigger):

[image]

**Output 2**(with return statement commented):

[image]

**Question**: Is there a way to update the trigger so that I can get the output I need. I cannot update the two conditions as one logic as the logic for each condition is very complex and we don't want to touch the existing logic.

Comment: What do you mean get the output you need? Both validations work as expected, no?

Comment: In the output 2 for the record 2, I want the error to be "Name cannot be test". I am not able to get this without adding the return statement. If I add return statement I am getting error on record 4(output 1)

Comment: @javanoob By the way, use `==` instead of `equalsIgnoreCase`. They do the same thing, but the latter throws an exception if the field is null...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a map and use the `sObjects` themselves as keys, eg:

```
Map<Account,String[]> accountErrors = new Map<Account,String[]>();

for(Account accObj: Trigger.new){
    if(accObj.Name.equalsIgnoreCase('Test')){
        if (!accountErrors.containsKey(accObj)){
          accountErrors.put(accObj,new String[]{'Name cannot be test'});
        }
        else {
          accountErrors.put(accObj,accountErrors.get(accObj).add('Name cannot be test'));
        }
    }
}

//Condition already present in the system
for(Account accObj: Trigger.new){
    if(accObj.BillingState.equalsIgnoreCase('MA')){
        if (!accountErrors.containsKey(accObj)){
          accountErrors.put(accObj,new String[]{'Please select different state'});
        }
        else {
          accountErrors.put(accObj,accountErrors.get(accObj).add('Please select different state'));
        }
    }       
}

//finally loop the errors map:
for (Account acct : accountErrors.keySet()){
  String[] errors = accountErrors.get(acct);
  for (String err : errors){
    acct.addError(err);
  }
}
```

You can extract the addition of errors to the map like so:

```
Map<Account,String[]> addCustomErrors(Map<Account,String[] accountErrors, Account accObj, String error){
    if (!accountErrors.containsKey(accObj)){
      accountErrors.put(accObj,new String[]{error});
    }
    else {
      accountErrors.put(accObj,accountErrors.get(accObj).add(error));
    }
    return accountErrors;

}
```

So inside your existing code you would only need to change:

```
accObj.addError('Name cannot be test');
```

To:

```
accountErrors = addCustomErrors(accountErrors,accObj,'Name cannot be test');
```

Comment: Looks like there is no easy way than rewriting the whole logic.

Comment: Well, look at my addition - you can just swap out one line for the other and it won't disrupt your code too much. And take note of what @Eric is saying - if all (or almost all) your records are failing, then you will continue to get failures.

Comment: This is awesome! creating a customAddError method seems easy then rewriting the whole logic.

Comment: Oh great. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @javanoob You could have just removed the "return" statement. All errors are aggregated through the trigger context.

Comment: @sfdcfox When I removed the return statement, for the record 2, I was getting the error as "Please select different State" and it is ignoring the first error "Name cannot be test". I want the error returned for record 2 to be "Name cannot be test" as it is the first condition failing before the check on state.

Comment: @javanoob Oh. I misread the code. You should be adding the errors *to each field*. Top-level errors should be reserved for situations where you can't identify the field, such as `accObj.Name.addError('Name cannot be test.');`

Comment: @sfdcfox You are genius! You helped me again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control order of precedence of trigger validations, you would need to adopt a pattern where you validate the collection, and then apply all validations on a record by record basis. What I mean by that is:

```
public with sharing class AccountService
{
    public static void validate(List<Account> records)
    {
        for (Account record : records) validate(record);
    }
    static void validate(Account record)
    {
        if (/*Condition 1*/)
        {
            record.addError('Message 1');
            return;
        }
        if (/*Condition 2*/)
        {
            record.addError('Message 2');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, I should rewrite the trigger like as you suggested but the existing code is too complex and I was looking for shortcut. I know shortcuts will break in the future or cause headache for future developers working on this code  :)